# Android In-App Subscriptions: How to set testing accounts without giving bank accounts information for In-app subscription?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have to integrate **In-app subscription** in my android application. For that, I have followed all the instructions as per this [URL](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Subs). I also getting my subscription product information with price but I can not getting dialog for testing account.For example, [image: image for in-app subscription test-accounts] **It always ask me to use Payment methods for real transactions** as per below image:[image: image for in-app subscription test-accounts].When I have added my credit card information, **It have done real transaction and debited my money**. I want to get **test subscription instead of real transactions**. I also refer [this reference link](https://hackernoon.com/inapp-subscription-setup-and-testing-v3-api-android-8239534b3e79). Please give me any suggestion for where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can refer [this reference link](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the issue.I have to remove permissions for test accounts, which I refer from this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html?rd=1)

**Test accounts have three limitations:**

1. Test account users can make purchase requests only within apps that
   are already uploaded to your publisher account (although the app
   doesn't need to be published).
2. Test accounts can only be used to purchase items that are listed
   (and published) in an app's product list
3. Test account users do not have access to your publisher account and
   cannot upload apps to your publisher account.